# Opencart 2.3.0.2 How to display products of a particular category in front page with a flag

Tags: javascript, php, opencart

I created a category called "coming soon" and I want products of that category to display in front page and in all products page with a flag "Coming soon." How do I proceed. Your Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download this module
[Show products of Category OpenCart 2.3.0.2 module for free](https://webocreation.com/blog/show-products-of-category-opencart-2-module-for-free)

Installation:

- Unzip the downloaded folder.
- Upload the files in root folder to your server, no file is overwritten.
- Then activate the “Category Products” module.

Comment: Thanks Rupak, I downloaded the module and it's working 100%. But the only problem is, it's displaying all the category products. How can I make it to display them in a carousel?